# API Platform - PATCH and ArrayCollection

Tags: doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I'm using API-Platform and faced an issue with updating many-to-many with an empty value.

Here is the small example:

```
/**
 * Many Organizations have Many Followers.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User\User", inversedBy="organizations")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="organizations_followers",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="organization_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
 *      )
 */
protected $followers;

/**
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getFollowers(): Collection
{
    return $this->followers;
}

/**
 * @param array $followers
 */
public function setFollowers(array $followers): void
{
    $this->followers = $followers;
}

/**
 * Organization constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->id = Uuid::uuid4();
    $this->followers = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

So, when I'm trying to delete all followers (PATCH request with empty followers in the relationships field) I always get one undeleted record. What am I doing wrong? Any Ideas?

Comment: Normally with a `toMany` relation you would use `add*` and `remove*` functions instead of `set*`. Have you tried that? Don't know how API-Platform does hydration, but in case it does not work as expected , you might have to look up how to create your own "strategy" for hydration and/or link-to-collection generation.